# Remove/Clear PDF document from Adobe Control

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdf-viewer

VB2012: I am using the Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library in my project to load PDF documents. Works great. However if the user enters an id for a document that doesn't exist I want to clear the current loaded PDF document. Otherwise the prior document stays in the viewer.

I tried:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(pdfFile) Then
    pdfViewer.LoadFile(pdfFile)
Else
    pdfViewer.LoadFile("")
    pdfViewer.LoadFile(Nothing)
End If
```

That doesn't seem to work and I cant find a method that clears or closes the current loaded document.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this too and found the `.visible` solution a little clunky.

I tried this and it worked:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(pdfFile) Then
    pdfViewer.LoadFile(pdfFile)
Else
    pdfViewer.LoadFile("none")
End If
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: Just noticed this post is over a year old (thought I was still in 2016).  Hopefully it'll help someone else though.

Comment: Excellent. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the comments by [sinDizzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428507/sindizzy):

> I chose to just make the PDF Viewer as `.Visible = False` at the beginning of processing. Then if an id does exist then I load the doc and turn `.Visible = True`, otherwise I leave it hidden.